# Unable to locate DEBIAN ARMv8 32-bit packages from Internet

Tags: linux, arm, debian, embedded

I have been trying to locate ARMv8 32bit package repository since yesterday to download packages that I would make use to carry out some analysis with radare. I had found repositories from [archlinux](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/coreutils) and [centos](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/aarch64/Packages/?C=S;O=D) but unfortunately all these packages are aarch64 (ARMv8-64bit) which radare is having issues with analyzing. I do not know exact reason for that issue but what my question is I want to find repositories like the above mentioned two for 32bit variant of ARMv8. I did find [termux](https://termux.net/dists/stable/main/binary-arm/) distribution of 32 bit ARM, but unfortunately it was ARMv7 instead of ARMv8.

In general following are my questions:

1. Is there a package repositories for ARMv8 32bit? Or ARMv8 is just 64bit?
2. Is there any general way of finding such repositories? (I did had a great difficulty in locating above mentioned repositories too, and knowing the way to finding such repositories would be really great)
3. When we mention ARMv8, is it generally referes to aarch64?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARMv7 is an 32-bit architecture, suporting aarch32 and thumb states. There are two types or packages provided for this plattform (as described [here](https://www.debian.org/ports/arm/)):

- `armel` using the older Embedded-ABI
- `armhf` using the newer Hard-Float-ABI

The ABI describes how values are exchanged between functions and with the operating system.

ARMv8 is a newer plattform, supporting the older 32-bit architectures from ARMv7 an the new 64-bit architecture with it's aarch64 state. There is only the `arm64` type of package provided for the 64-bit plattform. The 32-bit ones are like ARMv7.

These are the names for debian-based systems. I don't know the names of the archlinux and CentOS ones right now, but there should also be the new 64-bit packages and the older 32-bit packages.

**Short summary:** There are no separate 32-bit packages for ARMv8, these are the ARMv7 packages.

Comment: thanks. In that case can I take ARMv7-m as a subset of ARMv7? I know that there are variants like ARMv7-m and ARMv7-a. For example, lets say I have a binary compiled to run on a microcontroller having ARMv7-m architecture. Does the instructions within that binary are compatible with ARMv7-a?

Comment: ARMv7 first is the seventh generation of ARM processors. There are different versions: ARMv7-A for general applications, ARMv7-M for microcontroller applications and ARMv7-R for real-time applications. All support the basic 32-bit instruction set. However, some instruction set extensions are only supported by certain processors even within these versions. Therefore it cannot be said in general whether a program running on a ARMv7-M processor would also run on a ARMv7-A processor.